# About inheritance mapping and best practices in Java

Tags: java, hibernate, oop, jpa, inheritance

I'm learning about the ways of mapping inheritance from database to java with JPA/Hibernate. I've found several examples of how to do it, but not how to apply it.

Now, I'm trying to apply this knowledge on a small project, but I run into a problem where I can't do it the way I thought it would be ideal.

About the code below, the problem is: I have an "Expense" class that records a new expense (credit card debt, etc.), this debt has a creditor, which can be a person (PF) or institution (PJ). A expense has only one creditor, but I'm forced to model with one of each subclass.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "expense")
public class Expense {
    
    // CODE
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name =  "creditorPF")
    private CreditorPF creditorPF;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name =  "creditorPJ")
    private CreditorPJ creditorPJ;
    
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "creditor")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Creditor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idCreditor")
    protected Long id;
    
    @NonNull
    protected String description;   
}


@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "creditor_pf")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "idCreditor")
public class CreditorPF extends Creditor {

    private String cpf;
    
    @Builder
    public CreditorPF() {
        super("");
    }
    
    @Builder
    public CreditorPF(String cpf, String nome) {
        super(nome);    
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

}


@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "creditor_pj")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "idCreditor")
public class CreditorPJ extends Creditor {

    private String cnpj;
    
    @Builder
    public CreditorPJ(String cnpj, String nome) {
        super(nome);        
        this.cnpj = cnpj;
    }

    @Builder
    public CreditorPJ() {
        super("");
    }
}
```

This works fine, but I don't think it's a good design, because the design is allowing one more creditor per subclass, even if I add validations to prevent it, the design would be semantically incorrect.

Is there a way I can get a design like this code below, but that I can get the subclass information when I retrieve the object through hibernate?

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "expense")
public class Expense {
    
    // CODE
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name =  "creditor")
    private Creditor creditor;
    
}
```

Comment: What problem do you get when you try your desired Expense entity mappings? JPA Must have (and get) the type information to build a proper Creditor instance when building the Expense instance - Java can tell you the Creditor subclass from the instance, that is what instanceof, getClass etc are for

Answer (score 0):

In case of getting the Credit type from THROUGH the Expense Object ,there's no way besides using instanceof or getClass() as @Chris said ,btw it's preferable to use composition over inheritence,since it doesn't introduce this problem and preserves database consistency since you can"t be FORCED to have nullable fields, and in your case you can implement it using a class Creditor containing an enum which holds the creditor type since it's know to you ,hope this helps !